# Consuming WSDL in Clojure

Tags: clojure, wsdl

I need to consume a WSDL web service and the Java client-side code I've seen so far looks  bloated and complicated. I was wondering whether a cleaner solution might exist in Clojure so that I may perhaps implement that part in Clojure and expose a simpler API to the Java code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
cd your_project_dir/src
wsimport -p some.import.ns http://.../service?wsdl
```

It would create `./some.import.ns/*.class`. So you can just `use` them in your clojure project

```
(ns your.ns ...
  (:import [some.import.ns some_WS_Service ...]))

(let [port (-> (some_WS_Service.) 
               .getSome_WS_ServicePort]
  (... (.someMethod port) ...))
```

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't resist...I'd rewrite the `let` to use the threading macro `->` as follows: `[port (-> (some_WS_Service.) .getSome_WS_ServicePort)]`.

Comment: Good point! I didn't think about it. Anyway I don't think it changes anything.

Comment: @mobyte Thanks dude, saved me lots of time, You can use the `--keep` switch of `wsimport` to keep and use java files, but to get compiled by lein you need to config the java source path in project.clj, like `:java-source-paths ["src"]`

Answer (score 1):

Check out paos: https://github.com/xapix-io/paos

> Lightweight and easy-to-use library to build SOAP clients from WSDL files.

```
(require '[clj-http.client :as client])
(require '[paos.service :as service])
(require '[paos.wsdl :as wsdl])

(defn parse-response [{:keys [status body] :as response} body-parser fail-parser]
  (assoc response
         :body
         (case status
           200 (body-parser body)
           500 (fail-parser body))))

(let [soap-service   (wsdl/parse "http://www.thomas-bayer.com/axis2/services/BLZService?wsdl")
      srv            (get-in soap-service ["BLZServiceSOAP11Binding" :operations "getBank"])
      soap-url       (get-in soap-service ["BLZServiceSOAP11Binding" :url])
      soap-headers   (service/soap-headers srv)
      content-type   (service/content-type srv)
      mapping        (service/request-mapping srv)
      context        (assoc-in mapping ["Envelope" "Body" "getBank" "blz" :__value] "28350000")
      body           (service/wrap-body srv context)
      resp-parser    (partial service/parse-response srv)
      fault-parser   (partial service/parse-fault srv)]
  (-> soap-url
      (client/post {:content-type content-type
                    :body         body
                    :headers      (merge {} soap-headers)
                    :do-not-throw true})
      (parse-response resp-parser fault-parser)))
```